# Are there default parsers/formatter in Angular 1.x?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, formatter

Wondering are there any default parsers of formatters in Angular 1.x (specifically 1.4.4) ([documentation here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/docs/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers)) to understand if I should do `unshift` in some cases when I add new handler to those arrays.

As documentation says e.g. about parsers:

> Array of functions to execute, as a pipeline, whenever the control reads value from the DOM.

Is this (and formatters) array initially empty?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should unshift to add parsers or formatters:

Bother `$parsers` and `$formatters` are empty by default;

```js
function yourFormat() {
 return {
  require: 'ngModel',
  link: function ($scope, $elem, $attrs, $ctrl) {
      var ngModelCtrl = $ctrl;
   console.log(ngModelCtrl.$formatters);
   console.log(ngModelCtrl.$parsers);

   console.log("adding parsers and formatters");

   ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function (value) {
    return value + "+";
   });

   ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
    return value + "-";
   });

   console.log(ngModelCtrl.$formatters);
   console.log(ngModelCtrl.$parsers);
  }
 }
}
function YourController() {
  this.yourmodel = {};
}

angular
 .module('app', []);
angular
 .module('app')
 .directive('yourFormat', yourFormat)
        .controller('YourController', YourController);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
<form ng-controller="YourController as c">
  <your-format ng-model="c.yourmodel"></your-format>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: hi! And **Is this (and formatters) array initially empty?**